# VisualJS - examples of two-way communication using WebSockets?

Tags: asp.net, websocket

So, I hear that VisualJS has WebSockets via PokeIn somehow, but I cannot find examples where VisualJS is used, and where the server sends data to the client/webbrowser.

VisualJS gives, like for example VisualWebGUI, me the option to NOT write any client-side messy HTML/JS etc, but to build my web apps just as I would do with a normal WinForm-app.

That's great, but I would love to see that it also can integrate the WebSockets into the mix...

Are there any good examples of such?

Comment: I have searched on their webpage, on google etc but didnt see just that...

Answer (score 1):

Because VisualJS.NET is built on top of PokeIn, activating [websocket](http://www.pokein.com/Help/WebSocketFeature.aspx) for [PokeIn](http://pokein.com) enable it for [VisualJS.NET](http://visualjs.net)

http://www.pokein.com/Help/WebSocketFeature.aspx

Comment: I read about that already, but that doesnt really help. I was asking for some examples where you can clearly see that the server is doing the updating. It would also be great to see examples of how to address a specific user for updating, say, a ListBox - an example so that the server decides that the ListBox for a specific User needs to be updated...

Comment: just put the keys to web.config and you will see that its using websocket where it is available (browser support). all the updates are already user based. Or I don't get the question?

Comment: User A logs in, and then is staring at en empty ListBox. Then User B logs in, and stares at the ListBox. Then, the server decides that the ListBox for User A should add a text with "Hello User A!", but there should be no such update for User B. How is that done?

Comment: this is the default behavior of VisualJS.NET .. It creates own object per each user.

Comment: Zuuum - but there must be something more too it. If the application-server tells the WEBserver that User A shall add for example a String to a ListBox, how can the WEBserver address the correct user? I don't see any example of how that is done. Do u have such an example?

Comment: Ted - this is how PokeIn and VisualJS.NET works. They do this addressing for you by default. Pick any sample project from (PokeIn and VisualJS.NET)

Comment: Hi, I did check the VisualJS sample projects, I saw nothing of that "targeting of a specific user via WebSockets"...?

Comment: Ted, PokeIn handles that. You just develop the application without dealing with how message is delivered etc. Websocket (if configured) works internally without any special push.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer Zuuum, however, there must be something missing. PokeIn cannot determine what users gets an updated pushed by the appliation-server (not the webserver). [AppServer] --> [WebServer] --> [Browser/User]. When the [AppServer] sends "AddMeToListbox" for a specifc user, the [WebServer] must know on what WebSocket it is supposed to send to, or rather, when it does a listBox1.Items.Add("AddMeToListBox"), which browser gets updated? Where is the targeting? CAuse the webserver cannot know, right?

Comment: when a user connects to server. Server holds an object for that user and when you add something to that listbox under that object, it only does that operation on that specific user's client. All this targeting etc. managed by VisualJS.NET and PokeIn automatically.

Comment: Zuum: thanks for the answer. I dont think you understand. The user has already connected. Nothing is going on. The the application-server says "add object to list". That comes to the webserver backend somehow. How can that address it correctly, find that "object" that you mentioned? Thats the trick - where and how can I connect my user id (username, email address etc) to the "object" u mentioned? =)

Comment: When a client connects, PokeIn creates an object and dispose it when disconnects. You may use that object for registration of a listener to other service. When the event fires for that 'object' you send the message directly to the client. Since you have an object per client and unique clientId, it shouldn't be that hard to make them listening for events.